# Using c#, why are the letters r and b being interpreted as HTML breaks in label text and how can I stop it?

Tags: c#, html, split

I have some code that takes address text from a label and attempts to split that string by HTML line breaks to get each address line in a string array:

```
string[] straAddressLines = lbBillStreetAddress.Text.Split("<br/>".ToCharArray());
```

When the label contains a lower case r or b, the code is interpreting those characters as HTML breaks.  So for example, if the text is "1 Albert Street", the resulting array is:

```
[0]: 1 Al
[1]: e
[2]: t St
[3]: eet
```

Since there are no HTML breaks in the string, I would expect it to be:

```
[0]: 1 Albert Street
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening here and how I can stop that behaviour?  I've tried HTML and URL encoding/decoding but no difference.

Comment: Removed the `ToCharArray`.  By doing that you're telling it to split on every character in the string instead of the entire string.

Comment: ^^ You are _actually_ using this overload: Split(Char[]) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___ which splits by any letter in that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are passing a `char` array for `Split` method, so it splits the string by each character. Since you want to split by `<br/>` you need to pass it as a `string`, instead of `char[]`:

```
lbBillStreetAddress.Text.Split(new [] { "<br/>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you are using .NET 5+ (or .NET Core 2+) there is [a more convenient overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_) that just takes a string as separator:

```
lbBillStreetAddress.Text.Split("<br/>");
```

Comment: There's also an overload that would just work with `.Split("<br/>")` if they are at least using .Net Core 2.0 or later or .Net 5 or later

Comment: @juharr indeed, thanks. I have added it in the answer.